# CakePHP URL rewriting conflicts with CakeRequest::onlyAllow

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-2.3

I am using `$this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete');` so as to only allow the deletion of records that come from a `POST` request.

The problem is that I am using URL rewriting in my `.htaccess` file and it's changing the request from a `POST` to a `GET`

This is what my `.htaccess` file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /example

    RewriteRule ^homes/$    http://dev.example.com/          [R=301,L]    

    # if this is an existing folder/file then leave
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule . - [L]

    # if no trailing slash then redirect to url with trailing slash
    RewriteRule ^/?(.+)([^/])$ $1$2/ [NE,R=301,L]

    # internal rewrite to controller/dispatcher index.php
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I am using the `postLink` FormHelper to generate a delete button:

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), 
    array('
        controller'=>'posts', 
        'action' => 'delete',), 
    null, 
    __('Are you sure you want to delete "%s?"', $attachment['Post']['name'])); 
?>
```

The problem is that the action for the form that is generated from the helper does not already have the trailing slash so the htaccess rule steps in and ads this which esentially changes this from a `POST` method to a `GET`

Action url that's generated: `posts/delete/33579`
Action url that's needed: `posts/delete/33579/`

I have tried adding a slash in the `$this->Form->postLink()` function however Cake encodes the slash and changes it to a `%2F`.

I am using CakePHPH 2.3.1

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: onlyAllow() (or allowMethod() for 2.5+) should be the very first thing in your action :)

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're suggesting @mark?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakefest/blob/master/Controller/AttendanceController.php#L87) for example. It should be the first line in your action method. Otherwise SQL queries will be triggered unnecessarily.

Comment: I think the issue is that you were seeing code that I didn't mean to include in my question. That was just code I was using for testing purposes. I do have `$this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete');` as the first thing in my action.

Comment: You can always extend the helpers and overwrite the methods that generate the URLs so that a slash is appended. However what's the point of this anyways, why does it matter whether or not the URL has a trailing slash?

Comment: The answer is: Don't. Don't use the trailing slash, use the Cake standard (no trailing slash) - or see https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-trailing-slash

Comment: You are both probably right. I was adding it to work well with some other stuff I have so I'll probably just remove it all together. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard behaviour for a redirect. You have two options:

- Fixing the url that is generated. This is the most sensible one, as you can probably imagine
- Preventing the rule from matching if the request is a POST-request (or only let it match with a get request). You can do this with `%{THE_REQUEST}`

  ```
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /
  RewriteRule ^(.+)([^/])$ $1$2/ [NE,R=301,L]
  ```

Comment: Your code seems to work, but I'm a little nervous using it. Can this have any adverse affects or pose any security risks? Also, do you have any suggestions for fixing the url that is generated?

Comment: I don't know how CakePHP works, so I can't advise you on that. There are no security implications, since you should not use rewrites for security related things. I have however changed my answer a little bit, since the actual rewrite can be done much simpler as shown in the answer now.

Comment: Actually your first code worked a lot better. Your current code seems to add an additional trailing slash that breaks the application.

Comment: You are right; I apparently am not really awake right now.